# Sort NSMutableArray of objects by date

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray

```
self.objectSet = [NSMutableArray array]; 

//add objects to set

[self.objectSet sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *firstDate = [(Entity *)a createdAt];
    NSDate *secondDate = [(Entity *)b createdAt];
    return [secondDate compare:firstDate];
}];
```

I want to sort the nsmutablearray by createdAt date. However the above code has no effect on the displayed table view. The data is unsorted.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that "createdAt" is not the right property name, or there's some other reason why your dates are coming back nil.

Comment: @HotLicks you are right, plz post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to sort with sort descriptors?
Is it the same effect?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:YES];
[self.objectSet sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```